# Getting timeline status and post of specific friends at first place in Facebook(like users Interest used in cookies)

Tags: facebook

Whenever I open My Facebook Account I am getting the timeline status and post of the users which I used to like and read Mostly not on the basis of time. So if I have to see the posts of other users I have to finish reading the post of this users.

How can I change this so that I can read the posts which is recently sent and sent by any of my friend list not the friends which I used to like most.

I am thinking that Facebook is rendering the content on the basis of User Interest, Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you log in to Facebook, simply select the `News Feed` option on the left-hand side and choose `Most Recent` instead of `Top Stories`.

[image]

Posts displayed in the timeline will now be ordered chronologically.

P.S. Apparently Facebook may sometimes revert your preference to Top Stories. There isn't currently a way to stop them from doing that natively.

If you're using the [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) browser, you could install the [Facebook Most Recent Default](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-most-recent-defa/nekfocplekjmdnfnjkjnipgenjcgemmb) extension so that this preference is always chosen.

**Edit:** It seems like what you could be experiencing is related to the `Close Friends` feature. Go to the individual pages of these people who keep popping up and make sure that they are categorized as `Friends` instead of `Close Friends`.

If they have a star next to the `Friends` drop-down box, this means they're listed as a close friend and will have more newsfeed exposure. Just untick the `Close Friends` option and they will be reverted to regular friend.

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the top stories, I am getting the stories of specific friends, and pages only.

Comment: Updated my answer, this could be related to the Close Friends feature then.